# How to show pictures in jFrame, using java2d?

Tags: java, netbeans, bitmap, java-2d

I'm new on working with Java and Netbeans. In many others languages, it's a simple stuff to do. But after broke my brain thinking, I couldn't. My doubt is simple to explain.
How can I show bitmaps (stored on Hard Drive) in runtime, in a commom JFrame, using java2D? What I need to edit, and or create? Is it simple to do?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: _But after broke my brain thinking... I can't_ Before saying you can't you should at least try.

Comment: I really try, sir. I am not a good searcher, you can see... But all of my attempts were failures. (and forgive my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic process is use `Graphics#drawImage` to render an image you have previously loaded.

There are a number of things you need in order to achieve this...

- An image to paint
- A surface to paint on

Luckily, both these are relatively easy to achieve in Swing

- See `ImageIO` for reading images, [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)
- See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how to perform painting in Swing...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ShowMyImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ShowMyImage();
    }

    public ShowMyImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ImagePane pane = new ImagePane();
                try {
                    pane.setImg(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\hold\\thumbnails\\_MTCGAC__Pulling_Cords_by_Dispozition.png")));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public ImagePane() {
        }

        public void setImg(BufferedImage value) {
            if (img != value) {
                img = value;
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public BufferedImage getImg() {
            return img;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            BufferedImage img = getImg();
            return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            BufferedImage img = getImg();
            if (img != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight()- img.getHeight()) / 2;

                g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, sir. With this I get! I just need to study little bit about Exceptions and Graphics2D class. By the way, I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need, as was told below to extend JPanel class and override paintComponent method in it.

```
public class DrawImageClass extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Image image;
    public DrawImageClass(Image image) throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(image, null, null);
    }
}
```

And then create JFrame and add this class to it.

```
public class App {
    private static final int WIDTH=480, HEIGHT = 640;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(HEIGHT, WIDTH));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            DrawImageClass panel = new DrawImageClass(ImageIO.read(new File(App.class.getResource("/1.png").getPath())));
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(HEIGHT, WIDTH));
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("wrong path or smth other");
        }  
    }
}
```

Example for picture which is in resource folder in project

Comment: +1 for extending `JPanel`; +1 for overriding `paintComponent`; -1 for using `setPreferredSize`; -1 for not calling `super.paintComponent`; -1 for not providing a `ImageObserver` to the `drawImage` method; -1 for not using `JFrame#pack`; -1 for missing [initial thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); -1 for not printing the exception (ok, that's a nit-pick)

Comment: You-re mad :) It was concise scraps of code for understanding how to. And it worked

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the basic AWT package in java. You will need to extend the JFrame class and override its paintComponent method to display an image there. i.e.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private java.awt.Image bitmap = ImageIO.read(new File("myBitmap.bmp"));

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics graphics) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int w = bitmap.getWidth(null);
        int h = bitmap.getHeight(null);
        graphics.drawImage(bitmap, x, y, w, h, this);
    }
}
```

You can simply instantiate it then

```
MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
myFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

This is a basic example of course.

Comment: -1, JFrame does not have a paintComponent() method. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent). Then you add the panel to the frame. You would also typically invoke super.paintComponent() at the beginning of the method.

Comment: So... <@override> is new to me. It overwrite the parent method?

Comment: See: [Use @Override Liberally](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=223)